# grouping in sql in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this with three columns `From`, `To`, and `Symbol`:

```
From   To   Symbol
0      2    dog
2      5    dog
5      9    cat
9      15   cat
15     20   dog
20     40   dog
40     45   dog
```

I was trying to write an SQL query that groups records in a way that produces the following result:

```
From   To   Symbol
0      5    dog
5      15   cat
15     45   dog
```

That is, if the `From` and `To` values are continuous for the same `Symbol`, one result record is created with the smallest `From` and the largest `To` values and the `Symbol`. In the above example table, since the second record has a value of 2 in the `To` column which is not the same as the `From` value in the next record with the same `Symbol` (15, 20, dog), two result records are created for the same `Symbol` (dog).

I have tried to join the table to itself, then group by. But I could not figure out how exactly that can be done. I have to do this in **Microsoft Access**. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could  you have 0/2 dog and then 4/5 dog?  That is, 3 is skipped.  And, this sort of problem is simpler in almost any database *other than* MS Access.

Comment: I got close with `SELECT  T2.FROM, T1.To, T2.Symbol FROM MyTable T1 LEFT JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol AND T1.From = T2.To WHERE Not T2.From IS NULL`but still ended up with two dogs at the end.

Comment: The numbers cover a continuous range, so cases like 0/2 dog and 4/5 dog with 3 skipped is guaranteed to be non-existent. Can this be done with window functions (`partition by ... order by`) if I am using something that recognizes it (e.g. PostgreSQL)? In my case I was given an Access database. The solution by Gordon Linoff solved my problem. I am also curious about the case where there are gaps. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values have no overlaps and that gaps separate values, you can do this in MS Access with a trick.  You need to identify the adjacent symbols that are the same.  Well, you can identify them by counting the number of previous rows with *different* symbols (using a subquery).  Once you have this information, the rest is aggregation:

```
select symbol, min(from) as from, max(to) as to
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t as t2
              where t2.from < t.from and t2.symbol <> t.symbol
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by symbol, grp;
```

Gaps would make this problem much harder in MS Access.

Note:  Don't use reserved words or keywords for column names.  This code uses the names supplied in the question, but doesn't bother to escape them.  I think that just makes it harder to understand the query.

Comment: You'll need to square bracket `[FROM]` as a reserved word in the Select statements.

Comment: What do we need to do to handle cases with gaps using MS Access? Any ideas?

Comment: @RiceLi . . . My statement was not precise.  Gaps are fine -- if they go in different rows in the result set.  Another challenge are overlaps.  The data in this question has no such examples.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more appropriate data, if that is closer to the problem you need to solve.